# Can't visualize plotted Confusion Matrix

Tags: pandas, tensorflow, matplotlib, google-colaboratory, confusion-matrix

I am new to ML and learning the fundamentals.
I am working on Dog-vision dataset (https://www.kaggle.com/c/dog-breed-identification) and I am trying to plot a confusion matrix but can't get where I am doing wrong, need help!

My true_label looks like this

```
true_label[:10]
array([26, 96,  8, 15,  3, 10, 62, 82, 92, 16]
```

And predicted_label looks like this

```
predicted_l[:10]
array([26, 96,  8, 15,  3, 10, 62, 82, 92, 16]
```

They are almost same but not the whole elements in the array are same.

Then I had converted them into a panda dataframe, with code like this

```
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.metrics import confusion_matrix
classes=[]
for i in range(0, 99):
  classes.append(i)

cf_matrix = confusion_matrix(true_l, predicted_l)
cf_matrix_df = pd.DataFrame(cf_matrix, index=classes,columns=classes)
cf_matrix_df
```

And then the output is like this-
[image]

Then I tried to plot the **confusion matrix** with this dataframe
but it's not being plotted in correct manner. Here is the code and the output of my confusion matrix:-

```
import seaborn as sns
figure = plt.figure(figsize=(8, 8))
sns.heatmap(cf_matrix_df, annot=True,cmap=plt.cm.Blues)
plt.tight_layout()
plt.ylabel('True label')
plt.xlabel('Predicted label')
plt.show()
```

Output
[image]

If you need more info then please have a look on my notebook here.
https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1SoXJJNTnGx39uZHizAut-HuMtKhQQolk?usp=sharing

Comment: Please explain what are you trying to predict, what is exactly your problem? I just can see you have 2 arrays and you plotted them in heatmap. I don't know what you expect to get.

Comment: I am expecting to get a more visual confusion matrix! but the one I plotted is not looking relevant. Through the conf_matrix I want to see how many wrong predictions my model has made and similarly how many correct predictions.

Comment: Yes it's classification model. There are 120 classes that are unique breeds of dogs

Comment: Try to integrate scroll bars and increase the figure size/.

Comment: The link requires requesting access, so not very useful.

Comment: @TrentonMcKinney Thanks for your comment, but I can't help with this issue. Because you have to put yours's accessing key and this comes default with colab drive. :(

Comment: I had added the link to see the code with their respective output's. And I got the answer too :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make your plot better by removing `annot=True` argument, since it writes the data value in each cell. Simply remove this argument to get a better visualization:

```
sns.heatmap(cf_matrix_df, cmap=plt.cm.Blues)
```

UPDATE: Increasing the figure size `figsize()` will help to make visualization more clearer.

Comment: hey, this answer helped me :) but please add one more statement in your answer ===>

**increasing the figure size `figsize()` will help to make visualization more clearer.**